# Using braces in rm in makefiles

Tags: make

So I'm learning about Makefiles and in an example, I was to remove files in the clean part. I wanted to do something along the lines of `rm paper.{aux,pdf,bib,bbl}`, but when I did `make clean` it didn't recognize any files like that. Doing that remove command outside of the makefile works just fine. Do makefiles not play nice with braces like this? I didn't find much about braces in makefiles in contexts like this.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `make` uses `/bin/sh` as the shell by default - brace expansion is a feature of more complex shells such as `/bin/bash`.

You could set the shell explicitly within the Makefile ex.

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        @echo rm paper.{aux,pdf,bib,bbl}
```

See [The GNU make manual: 5.3.2 Choosing the Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#Choosing-the-Shell)